# Как выключить звук Windows 10 на python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выключить звук на Windows 10, используя python3, даже если выключен все равно попробовать выключить

Answer (score 0):

С помощью этой [библиотеки](https://github.com/Paradoxis/Windows-Sound-Manager)

> from sound import Sound
>   Sound.mute()